# Ruby 1.9.3 Regex utf8 \w accented characters

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, utf-8

How ensure \w in Regexp treat national letters same as normal letters ?

```
'ein grüner Hund'.scan(/\S+/u)
```

> ["ein", "grüner", "Hund"]

It scans correctly the "ü" as non whitespace character.

```
'ein grüner Hund'.scan(/\w+/u)
```

> ["ein", "gr", "ner", "Hund"]

How get the "ü" too ?

I need a solution not only for german, french and polish characters should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`'ein grüner Hund'.scan(/[[:word:]]+/u)`

[Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)

Answer (score 2):

`\w` will work for letter or digit or underscore. Your regex engine might be considering a **single Unicode code point** as a **single character**. In that case, **ü** will not be matched as a single character as it is **multiple code point** character (encoded as two code points). For matching multiple code point characters also, use `\X` which matches a single unicode grapheme whether it is single code point or multiple code point.

Check [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for more information.

I'm not sure whether Ruby supports `\X`. Otherwise `\p{L}\p{M}*` can be used, which matches a letter along with accent.

Comment: +1 for " In that case, ü will not be matched as a single character as it is multiple code point character (encoded as two code points)"